# How to reference or "find" a PreferenceActivity?

Tags: android, preferenceactivity

I have legacy code which extends PreferenceActivity with a subclass called "Preferences". The PreferenceActivity is invoked as follows:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Preferences.class);
    this.startActivity(intent);
```

The OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener exists in a another fragment (not the PreferenceActivity subclass) but needs a reference to the PreferenceActivity in order to modify attributes of a custom preference/control similar to the following:

```
    pref = (CheckBoxPreference) prefActivity.findPreference(res.getString(R.string.keyAccount));
    pref.setSummary("something");
```

where "prefActivity" is the reference to the PreferenceActivity. Can anyone suggest how to save a reference to the PreferenceActivity when it is created or otherwise locate the PreferenceActivity when needed?

**EDIT:** Including the grossly oversimplified code to hopefully help show hierarchies and clarify.

The FragmentActivity CPActivity instantiates CPFragment and on demand (a button press) creates an Intent to fire off a PreferenceActivity subclass (called "Preferences").

```
public class CPActivity extends FragmentActivity
{
public static CPActivity inst;
private CPFragment mFragmentCP;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    inst = this;
    mFragmentCP = new CPFragment();
    }

    public void onSettingsButtonPressed() {
    // Bring up the Preferences menu
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Preferences.class);
    this.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

CPFragment is our shared preference listener (among other things). It is in this code, where we'd like to modify a custom preference control/entry (that is, not the preference value itself, rather attributes on the preference control, e.g. a CheckBoxPreference). We'd like to do it here because this is where the pertinent data is calculated.

```
public class CPFragment extends Fragment implements OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener 
{
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
    // In response to preference changes, we want to modify the PreferenceActivity controls.
    // So it seems we would need a reference to the PreferenceActivity subclass "Preferences
    }
}
```

And finally, the PreferenceActivity subclass "Preferences" does little more than bring up the Settings view.

```
    public class Preferences extends PreferenceActivity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences_cp);
    }
}
```

As I mentioned, we'd prefer to be able to modify the Custom Preference in CPFragment (as opposed to the PreferenceActivity). Therefore I was looking for some way of locating the PreferenceActivity while responding as onSharedPreferenceChangeListener in CPFragment.

Comment: I think you are getting downvoted because the question is unclear. Please clarify what you are asking. Are you trying to update your `Preferences` activity from a `Fragment`? You can register a `OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener` from the activity too.

Comment: Hmmm... not sure what is unclear, I state "OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener exists in a another fragment (not the PreferenceActivity subclass)".But in this other Fragment I need to modify a custom preference. So I need a reference somehow to the PreferenceActivity in order to modify the custom preference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you have an `Activity` named `Preferences` which `extends` [`PreferenceActivity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html). You also have a `Fragment` that has registered an [`OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener.html). You need to update the UI in your `Preferences` `Activity` but you are not sure how to accomplish this.

Is the `Fragment` attached to the `Preferences` `Activity`? If it is, then you should be able to do the following in your `Fragment`:

```
if (getActivity() instanceof Preferences) {
  Preferences activity = (Preferences) getActivity();
  CheckBoxPreference pref = (CheckBoxPreference) activity.findPreference(getString(R.string.keyAccount));
  pref.setSummary("something");
}
```

---

**Another approach:**

You can also register an [`OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener.html) in your `Preferences` `Activity` and you will get notified when the preference changes. Example:

```
public class Preferences extends PreferenceActivity implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

  /* ... */

  @Override protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    prefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
  }

  @Override public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
    if (key.equals(getString(R.string.keyAccount))) {
      CheckBoxPreference pref = (CheckBoxPreference) findPreference(key);
      pref.setSummary("something");
    }
  }

  @Override protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    prefs.unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
  }

  /* ... */

}
```

---

**Some things to consider based on your edited answer:**

**1)** Never create a `static` reference to your `Activity`. `public static CPActivity inst;`. This can lead to memory leaks.

**2)** Consider moving code in your `Preferences` `Activity` to a [`PreferenceFragment`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceFragment.html).

**3)** It is still unclear what you are trying to achieve. Is the `CheckBoxPreference` that you want to modify in your `CPFragment` or the `Preferences` `Activity`?

**4)** You should still consider using two [`OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener.html)s or an [EventBus](http://android-arsenal.com/tag/32).

Comment: Your understanding of the question is correct. I have a FragmentActivity that does the startActivity that initiates the PreferenceActivity. 

Regarding your "Another approach" suggestion, I did mention in the Bounty posting that registering an OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener in the  PreferenceActivity subclass was not a good option.

Comment: Sorry, no the fragment is not attached to the PreferenceActivity.  I think another option would be to save a reference to the PreferenceActivity when it's startActivity is called... but I do not understand how to do this.

Comment: You can have both the `Fragment` and `Activity` register an `OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener`. It isn't a good idea to reference an `Activity` that is not in the foreground. You should post some code, otherwise I'm not sure how else to help.

Comment: Attempted to clarify the code hierarchy in the original post. Hope that helps.

Comment: @Electro-Bunny I updated my answer based on your edit.

Comment: Thanks, CPFragement is where I want to modify the CheckBoxPreference.

Comment: your efforts are appreciated (and apologies if my question took excessive clarification). I have not yet tried this out, but the insight to using an EventBus might be the "workaround". I suppose my CPFragment could signal the PreferenceActivity to make the mods to the custom preference.